# Unable to install TeamViewer

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

Trying to install TeamViewer on Ubuntu 21.10 on a Pi 4.

Tried installing through the Ubuntu Software, but was met with a message saying it was unable to install due to unmet dependencies.

Downloaded and tried to install through terminal and I get this

```
$ sudo apt install ./teamviewer_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'teamviewer:amd64' instead of './teamviewer_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 teamviewer:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libdbus-1-3:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libexpat1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libfontconfig1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libfreetype6:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libglib2.0-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libgl1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libice6:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libminizip1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libnspr4:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libnss3:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libsm6:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libx11-6:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libx11-xcb1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-glx0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-icccm4:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-image0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-keysyms1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-randr0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-render0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-render-util0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-shape0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-shm0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-sync1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-xfixes0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-xinerama0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcb-xkb1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcomposite1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxcursor1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxdamage1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxext6:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxfixes3:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxi6:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxkbcommon0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxrandr2:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxrender1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxss1:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libxtst6:amd64 but it is not installable
                    Depends: zlib1g:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried the Raspberry Pi versions and get this:

```
$ sudo apt install ./teamviewer-host_armhf.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'teamviewer-host:armhf' instead of './teamviewer-host_armhf.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 teamviewer-host:armhf : Depends: libc6:armhf (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libdbus-1-3:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libexpat1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libfontconfig1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libfreetype6:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libglib2.0-0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libgl1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libice6:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libminizip1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libnspr4:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libnss3:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libsm6:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libx11-6:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libx11-xcb1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-glx0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-icccm4:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-image0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-keysyms1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-randr0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-render0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-render-util0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-shape0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-shm0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-sync1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-xfixes0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-xinerama0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcb-xkb1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcomposite1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxcursor1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxdamage1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxext6:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxfixes3:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxi6:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxkbcommon0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxrandr2:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxrender1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxss1:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxtst6:armhf but it is not installable
                         Depends: zlib1g:armhf but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried installing a few of the packages, but they already seem to be installed and I've checked and there doesn't appear to be and held packages either.

Also ran

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

But this has done nothing to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your RPi uses *arm64*/*aarch64* (not *armhf* and of course not *amd64/x86_64*) distro, so you need to use [TeamViewer host](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/) for this architecture:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer-host_arm64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./teamviewer-host_arm64.deb
```

Comment: Can `apt-get` install deal with `.deb` file?

Comment: Yes. And it will satisfy dependencies for us.

Comment: Sweet ! I always relied to `gdebi` though :p

Answer (score 0):

Your output shows two problems:

1. The Pi4 uses a different architecture than `amd64`.

   - amd64-specific packages like the one you specified (`teamviewer_amd64.deb`) cannot be installed on non-amd64 systems.
   - For a Raspberry Pi, use the Pi-specific Teamviewer package.
2. Ubuntu 20.10 is no longer supported, and its repositories have been withdrawn.

   - Migrate to a supported release of Ubuntu: 18.04 LTS (until July 2023), 20.04 LTS (until July 2025), 21.04 (until Jan 2022), or 21.10 (until July 2022)